# button and label text not showing

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

[image: Pictures Here]

the two windows in the picture are exact copies(same line of code), only difference being that the right window is a screen inside a screen manager, but somehow the window on the right does not show the texts.

i'm not sure what the problem is and can't find anything related to it while doing research.

**RIGHT WINDOW PYTHON FILE:**

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.config import Config
space = ""

x = [(a * 9), (a*16)]
Config.set('graphics', 'width', x[0])
Config.set('graphics', 'height', x[1])

class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass

class SecondScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ThirdScreen(Screen):
    pass


kv = Builder.load_file("main2.kv")
class ComplimentUI(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv
    def change_screen(self, x):
        scrnmanager = self.root.ids['sm']
        scrnmanager.current = x

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ComplimentUI().run()
```

**RIGHT WINDOW BUILDER FILE:(main2.kv)**

```
#:include secondscreen.kv
#:include thirdscreen.kv

<MainScreen>:
    canvas.before:
         Color:
            rgb: .59, .74, .20
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
        FloatLayout:
            TextInput:
                pos_hint: {'center_x':1, 'top':.1}
                size_hint: .1,.1
                multiline: False
                font_size: 20
                font_name: "Dimbo Regular"
                background_normal: ''
                background_color: 0,0,0,0

            Button:
                text: "PLAY!"
                pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.3}
                size_hint: .8, .17
                font_name: "Splatch"
                color: 0.15, .5, 0.2, 1
                font_size: 0.14 * self.width
                background_normal: ''
                background_color: 0,0,0,0
                on_press:
                print("pressed, navigating to prev screen")
                app.change_screen("screentwo")
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgb: 1,1, .8,1
                    RoundedRectangle:
                        size: self.size
                        pos: self.pos
                        radius: [4,]

ScreenManager:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        ScreenManager:
            id: sm
        MainScreen:
            name: "screenone"
            id: screenone
        SecondScreen:
            name: "screentwo"
            id: screentwo
        ThirdScreen:
            name: "thirdscreen"
            id: thirdscreen[enter image description here][1]
```

**LEFT WINDOW PYTHON FILE:**

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.config import Config
space = "";

x = [(a * 9), (a*16)]
Config.set('graphics', 'width', x[0])
Config.set('graphics', 'height', x[1])

kv = Builder.load_file("main.kv")
class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()
```

**LEFT WINDOW BUILDER FILE:(main.kv)**

```
FloatLayout:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb: .59, .74, .20
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    TextInput:
        pos_hint: {'center_x':1, 'top':.1}
        size_hint: .1,.1
        multiline: False
        font_size: 20
        font_name: "Dimbo Regular"
        background_normal: ''
        background_color: 0,0,0,0

    Button:
        text: "PLAY!"
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.3}
        size_hint: .8, .17
        font_name: "Splatch"
        color: 0.15, .5, 0.2, 1
        font_size: 0.14 * self.width
        background_normal: ''
        background_color: 0,0,0,0
        on_press:
            print("pressed, navigating to prev screen")
            app.change_screen("screentwo")
            root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgb: 1,1, .8,1
            RoundedRectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
                radius: [4,]
```

**NEW EDIT:**

as i pointed out in the comment below, the same problem happens with the FloatLayout of `secondscreen.kv` and `thirdscreen.kv`, if i put it inside the builder file of the left window, its normal. But when i put it inside a screen inside a screen manager(like the right window) it's gone. the same problem happens to all my screens. the reason i only put the `mainscreen.kv` is because its the shortest out of all the screens, but nonetheless i will still provide the files, but only 1 version of it (the one used for the right window) since they're basically the same lines. (only difference being the added first line for its class name and a slight indetation change to fit the levels)

**SECONDSCREEN BUILDER FILE:**

```
<SecondScreen>:
    FloatLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgb: .59, .74, .20
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        TextInput:
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.56}
            size_hint: .8, .3
            multiline: False
            font_size: 20
            font_name: "Dimbo Regular"
            background_normal: ''
            background_color: 1, 1, .8, 1

        Label:
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.76}
            size_hint: .8, .07
            text: "NAME!"
            font_size: 0.8 * self.height
            font_name: "kidsrock"
            color: 0.15, .5, 0.2, 1
            background_color: 0,0,0,0
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgb: 1,1, .8,1
                RoundedRectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
                    radius: [4,]

        Button:
            text: "<<<"
            size_hint: .28, .07
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.24, 'center_y':.1}
            font_name: "kidsrock"
            color: 0.15, .5, 0.2, 1
            font_size: 0.35 * self.width
            background_normal: ''
            background_color: 0,0,0,0
            on_press:
                print("pressed, navigating to prev screen")
                app.change_screen("screenone")
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgb: 1,1, .8,1
                RoundedRectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
                    radius: [4,]
        Button:
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.8, 'center_y':.35}
            size_hint: .2, .07
            background_normal: ''
            background_color: 0,0,0,0
            color: 0.15, .5, 0.2, 1
            text: "ENTER"
            font_name: "kidsrock"
            font_size: 0.25 * self.width
            on_press:
                print("pressed, navigating to next screen")
                app.change_screen("thirdscreen")
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgb: 1,1, .8,1
                RoundedRectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
                    radius: [4,]
```

**THIRDSCREEN BUILDER FILE:**

```
<ThirdScreen>:
    FloatLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgb: .59, .74, .20
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        TextInput:
            pos_hint: {'center_x':1, 'top':.1}
            size_hint: .1, .1
            multiline: False
            font_size: 20
            font_name: "Dimbo Regular"
            background_normal: ''
            background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0

        Label:
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.71}
            size_hint: .8, .17
            text: "COMPLIMENT!"
            font_size: 20
            font_name: "kidsrock"
            color: 0.15, .5, 0.2, 1
            background_color: 0,0,0,0
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgb: 1,1, .8,1
                RoundedRectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
                    radius: [4,]

        Button:
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.24, 'center_y':.1}
            size_hint: .28, .07
            font_name: "kidsrock"
            color: 0.15, .5, 0.2, 1
            font_size: 0.35 * self.width
            text: "<<<"
            background_normal: ''
            background_color: 0,0,0,0
            on_press:
                print("pressed, navigating to prev screen")
                app.change_screen("screentwo")
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgb: 1,1, .8,1
                RoundedRectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
                    radius: [4,]
```

**NEW- NEW EDIT!:**

UPDATE
after restarting my computer, it now looks like this.

[image]

Comment: You have indentation problem in your posted kv file. Is the right screen shot for SecondScreen? Could you please share kv language for SecondScreen.

Comment: woops so sorry i made this veryy confusing. first of all yes, i do think that the indetation on the code i have shown is wrong, but i believe its just because StackOverflows formatting, not the code itself. second, no the the right screen is not SecondScreen, the right window is MainScreen, and its line of code is shown above. Also, the windows showed in the picture runs from 2 different python files, I'll try to edit and add the Left Window's script but im not sure it'll make a lot of difference.

Answer (score 1):

## Root Cause - Button & Label text not showing

The most probable cause is that the default [color](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.label.html#kivy.uix.label.Label.color) for text is white ([1, 1, 1, 1]), and the background color for both widgets are also white. You need to set the text color to non-white e.g. black ([0, 0, 0, 1]).

## TextInput Box - not showing

The TexInput box is not visible in both windows (left & right) because of `background_normal: ''` and `background_color: 0,0,0,0`.

Comment them off and the TextInput box will be visible.

## Button's text, 'PLAY' - not showing in right window

It could be something in the include kv files e.g. `secondscreen.kv`, and/or `thirdscreen.kv` that are/is causing the visibility. Comment off both kv files to trouble shoot the problem.

## Example

The following example of the right window i.e. using `ScreenManager` is able to display the `Button`'s text, "PLAY" and also the `TextInput` box.

### main-right.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder


class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass


class SecondScreen(Screen):
    pass


class ThirdScreen(Screen):
    pass


kv = Builder.load_string("""
# :include secondscreen.kv
# :include thirdscreen.kv

<MainScreen>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb: .59, .74, .20
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    FloatLayout:
        TextInput:
            hint_text: 'Type here'
            pos_hint: {'center_x':1, 'top':.1}
            size_hint: .1,.1
            multiline: False
            font_size: 20
            # font_name: "Dimbo Regular"
            # background_normal: ''
            # background_color: 0,0,0,0

        Button:
            text: "PLAY!"
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.3}
            size_hint: .8, .17
            #font_name: "Splatch"
            color: 0.15, .5, 0.2, 1
            font_size: 0.14 * self.width
            background_normal: ''
            background_color: 0,0,0,0
            on_press:
                print("pressed, navigating to prev screen")
                app.change_screen("screentwo")
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1, 1, .8, 1
                RoundedRectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
                    radius: [4,]

GridLayout:
    cols: 1
    ScreenManager:
        id: sm
        MainScreen:
            name: "screenone"
            id: screenone
        SecondScreen:
            name: "screentwo"
            id: screentwo
        ThirdScreen:
            name: "thirdscreen"
            id: thirdscreen
""")


class RightWindow(App):
    title = "ComplimentUI"

    def build(self):
        return kv


if __name__ == "__main__":
    RightWindow().run()
```

## Output

[image: Result]

Comment: in the code i've provided, the color of the text is  rgba(0.15, 0.5, 0.2, 1) which is the shade of forest green shown on the left window.

Comment: By running what you have provided, we are not able to reproduce the problem. You need to provide more i.e. [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I'll make an edit, I'll try to provide the python files of both windows, but im sorry that I'm not sure of anything else that'll help.

Comment: Try commenting off the include files, `secondscreen.kv` and `thirdscreen.kv`. Please refer to my updated post for more details.

Comment: the same problem occurs in secondscreen.kv and thirdscreen.kv. it's the same thing, if i put the layout of the secondscreen.kv/ thirdscreen.kv in the left builder file, it shows normally. but if i put it inside a screen, in a screen manager(like the right window) the problem happens. and about the textinput, i knowingly put it like that, my other widgets somehow get discoloured if i put its line of code after FloatLayouts canvas.before, so i just put an invisible textinput as the first line of code after the FloatLayouts canvas.before. at this point im afraid that its only a glitch on my part.

Comment: i made the edit, and as u can see, in both builder files i also put the invisible TextInput widget first, since it prevents the other Widget from getting dicoloured. And I thank you so so much for actually trying to help me, i actually very appreciate it man, thanks alot.

Comment: With `secondscreen.kv` and `thirdscreen.kv` included, I am not able to reproduce the problem. Do you mind sharing your project in GitHub?

Comment: no at all! heres the link https://github.com/teslaawasntcrazy/ComplimentGUI, i appreciate you going this far to help me. while we're at  do u mind if i ask u to also help me with why/how my popup not dismissing?

Comment: Unable to reproduce the problem with the version from GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar problem and the bug for me turned out to be a declaration of size_hint_x for the button. Once I removed that, the text was visible.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it because of that I used [font version](https://rastikerdar.github.io/vazirmatn/en/docs/Vazirmatn-Files-fa) that doesn't includes Latin characters but Persian I changed the version and problem being gone.